# Pagination links not including type of activity

Tags: sony-lifelog-api

When making a call including the "type" parameter, only the first page actually seems to be affected. The link to the next page does not include the parameter, and thus the following pages are unaffected.

Is this an error in the API, or are developers supposed to include this themselves?

Answer (score 0):

So you should be able to take that exact "href" url in the return json and use that to get the next set of data.

```
 "links":  [
 {
  "rel": "next",
  "href": " -- copy this link --"
```

I know that it does not include the type, but if you look at the dates and the data returned it should be the next data set.

I would recommend testing this out in the online API explorer just to verify that it works:

https://developer.sony.com/develop/services/lifelog-api/api-explorer/

With this query:

https://platform.lifelog.sonymobile.com/v1/users/me/activities?type=physical